# I've noticed some engineers bootstrap containers, such as Spring / Mironaut in their Unit Tests. Unit Test or Integration Test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, integration-testing

I'm getting confused here.   I am from the school of thought where a Unit Test is about testing the Class Under Test, and mocking out it's immediate collaborators (some exceptions to this general rule here!).

However, some of my colleagues have a slightly different opinion in that they feel it's okay to bootstrap a Dependency Injection container in a Unit Test.   To me this feels like the test is testing more than the Class Under Test because the DI container can automagically inject other dependencies which are irrelevant to the test.

Comment: Too bad the question is closed, I would have a nice answer. Anyway, the short answer is: turn to the wikipedia article for unit tests. Read the definition carefully. It boils down to "any kind of test that you do to test any kind of system" ... can be considered a unit test. In other words: the term itself is not clearly defined. You coworkers are right: you can legally have unit tests that make use of real spring. **BUT** personally, I consider that definition to be useless. A *real* unit test is cutting out *all* such dependencies. You test **only** the unit under test.

Comment: Anything beyond that, that uses "more" (or all) parts of the later production setup is either a functional test, or an integration test. So, I hope my comments help with your question. If you really like my input and show your appreciation, feel free to visit my profile and check out other answers of mine ;-)

Comment: Then also look up Blackbox and Whitebox Testing. How big is the unit you want to keep as a black box, because you want to avoid creating too many dependencies from the implementation.